# How to replace underscores with spaces?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array with objects inside of it, a few of the objects contain an underscore in the string.

Example:

```
{"name": "My_name"}
```

But I'm calling the name function in multiple places, one such place is in an image tag where the underscore is necessary, using JavaScript I want to select a certain div with the name in it and replace the underscore with space.

Example:

```
<div>
 <div class="name">
  My_name
 </div>
 <img src="My_name.jpg"/>
</div>
```

In the `div.name` I want it to say `My name` instead of `My_name`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace all occurrences of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You can replace all underscores in a string with a space using `String.prototype.replace` with a global regular expression:

```
str.replace(/_/g, ' ')
```

So just do that before the content is put in. Or, if you need to perform the replacement afterwards, the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) solution is:

```
$('.name').text((i, oldText) =>
    oldText.replace(/_/g, ' '));
```

which is equivalent to this plain DOM API loop:

```
for (const element of document.getElementsByClassName('name')) {
    element.textContent = element.textContent.replace(/_/g, ' ');
}
```

Comment: note that there are no single or double quotes for the first part written in regex

Answer (score 18):

ES2021 introduced the nifty [replaceAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)-function which means it can be written as:

```
str.replaceAll('_', ' ')
```

If you want to do multiple elements just loop over them and use [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.name')   
elements.forEach(e => e.innerText = e.innerText.replaceAll('_', ' '))
```

Comment: Good to know, I haven't had much chance to review ES2021 just yet but this is useful information indeed