# How to trim underscore (_) from a text

Tags: javascript, html, trim

Let's say I have a string `'Hello_World'`.

How do I remove `'_'` from the string for it to be  `'Hello World'`?

I have seen various trim examples like the following from w3schools:

```
function myTrim(x) {
    return x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');
}
```

to remove whitespaces from a string. I dont know how to remove an underscore using the same methodology.

Comment: Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810569/javascript-replace-underscore-with-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `replace(/_/g,' ')` to remove all underscore globally from the string:

```js
var res = "Hello_World".replace(/_/g,' ');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Should you not close it as dupe instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can try by replacing with the following regex
s/_//g

Answer (score 2):

A non-regex way can be:

```
var string = 'Hello_World';
string = string.split('_').join('');
console.log(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

for example you can use this:

```
var mystring = "this_is_a_test"
console.log(mystring.replace(/_/g , ""));
```